# converting a string to a list of integers

Tags: c#, string

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C#.NET 3.5 application where I have a string with a list of numbers separated by a semicolon.

```
string num_list = "1;2;3;4;201;2099;84"
```

I would like to convert that to a `List<int>`. Is there an easier way than this?

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>();
foreach (string num in num_list.Split(';'))
    foo.Add(Convert.ToInt32(num));
```

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 List<int> foo = num_list.Split(';').Select(num => Convert.ToInt32(num)).ToList();
```

Comment: Couldn't you simplify the "Select" to `Select(Convert.ToInt32)`?

Comment: @Cpfohl I'm not sure if that'll compile.

Comment: @Cpfohl - When I try that, I get an error saying `The Type arguments for method ... cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Alternative is `List<int> foo = num_list.Split(';').Select<string, int>(int.Parse).ToList();`

Comment: @StackOverflowException - Fancy!

Comment: +1 With the assistance of ReSharper 'Convert to Method Group' hint, I got it down to
var foo = num_list.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

```
num_list.Split(';').Select( o => int.Parse(o)).ToList();
```